# Bootstrap 4-How to sort table with arrow icon changing color based on ASC/DESC

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatables, tablesorter

I would like to sort an table in asc and desc order.Basically when i click fa-sort-asc this should be highlighted and fa-sort-desc should be greyed out and vice-versa.
Please help me how to achieve this in Bootstrap 4. There are examples but when ASC sort is done the down arrow is missing.

I also tried with datatables but i have no luck. Please help me what i need to add to make the sorting enable with color highlights

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="th-sm">ID
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Age
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Name
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>San Franisco</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>London</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

     // $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/saranya2020/kgp68vuh/7/

Comment: Isn't the example here https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html already doing that?

Comment: @David Liang: Yes! But im not getting arrow symbol.Thats the main part.Added all the specified libraries. Please let me know what i have missed..

Comment: Hmmm weird. By inspecting the up and down arrow, they're just unicode characters: `\2191` and `\2193` (https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css#L108). It shouldn't need to reference any library. Are you able to provide a jsfiddle so that we all can see your problem?

Comment: Working fiddle with Table sorter: https://jsfiddle.net/saranya2020/kgp68vuh/7/  ,but i need to retain and blur the arrow which is not clicked .

Comment: @DavidLiang: Please help me out! In simple i would like to work my fiddle as datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html sample and to sort whole table list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your jsfiddle is not using [datatables](http://datatables.net/), nor [Bootstrap](https://www.getbootstrap.com/). It's using [jquery.tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) so I don't know what's up with that. You might need to update the tags if you're planning to use tablesorter instead of datatables with Bootstrap then.

Secondly, it seems like your jsfiddle demo is missing jQuery, and setting the theme to "bootstrap". Have you read the [documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-theme-bootstrap-v4.html) about how to use bootstrap theme in tablesorter.js?

Third, from [tablesorter bootstrap theme demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-theme-bootstrap-v4.html), its author is saying

> Bootstrap v4.x no longer includes fonts or images, so I didn't bother including Font Awesome icons on this demo page.

Maybe that was why the up/down arrows didn't show up because tablesorter.js uses images for the sorting icons.

Now in order to add sorting icons (maybe from Font Awesome's), you can't really change the header structure and add icons in it. The trick here is to style `:before` and `:after` of `.tablesorter-header` to use content `\f0de` (Font Awesome up arrow) and `\f0dd` (Font Awesome down arrow):

```css
.tablesorter-header {
    position: relative;          /* This is needed for the absolute positioning. */
}

.tablesorter-header::before,
.tablesorter-header::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.75em;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';  /* Use FontAwesome's font so that you can set the content */
    opacity: 0.3;                /* Set opacity to gray out icons by default */
}

.tablesorter-header::before {
    content: '\f0de';            /* Font Awesome's up arrow */
    top: calc(50% - 0.75em);     /* Tricky to calculate the top offset */
}

.tablesorter-header::after {
    content: '\f0dd';            /* Font Awesome's down arrow */
    bottom: calc(50% - 0.75em);
}

.tablesorter-header.tablesorter-headerAsc::before,
.tablesorter-header.tablesorter-headerDesc::after {
    opacity: 1;                  /* When sorting, set full opacity on the direction */
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/hdL0723p/39/

Comment: Could you please help me out how to avoid auto expansion of one of my column during sorting. In my table first column has +icon which only on clicking it expands and shows up few data. But now after applying sorting as per  jsfiddle.net/saranya2020/kf7vdgnq/57 when i do sorting my column auto expands and table looks wierd.

Comment: With normal html the display:none works fine. But when i include tablesorter this style is not recognizing and always displays the row irrespective of condition. Please help me how to sort this

Comment: You might want to create a separate post and ask people around. I am not an export of tablesorter. I only used datatables before.

Comment: Sure David. Have created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137954/auto-expansion-of-column-when-table-sorter-function-called.